# How to create function with this elements

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my javascript code. This code is for two containers. When the one is opened, and I want to open the second. I select the second and It closes the first. This also works If second is opened and I want to open the first. I click the first one and It closes the second. My question is how to make a function  to add more .selected(3,4,5,6) .option-container(3,4,5,6), .option(3,4,5,6)... Because this way is not efficient to add them manually.

```
const optionsContainer1 = document.querySelector(".option-container1");
const selected2 = document.querySelector(".selected2");
const optionsContainer2 = document.querySelector(".option-container2");

const optionsList1 = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
const optionsList2 = document.querySelectorAll(".option2");

selected1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer1.classList.toggle("active");
    optionsContainer2.classList.remove("active");
});
optionsList1.forEach(o => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected1.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer1.classList.remove("active");
    });
});

selected2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer2.classList.toggle("active");
    optionsContainer1.classList.remove("active");
});
optionsList2.forEach(o => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected2.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer2.classList.remove("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: add html and css code as well and what is this .selected(3,4,5,6) ? is this a function

Comment: Agreed - the html and css might be pertinent here.  Also, can you explain what you expect to see after `.selected(3,4,5)`?  is it that sections 3,4,5 would be open and all other sections should be closed?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to first stock all your containers in an array.

```
let containerArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container'));
```

The `[].slice.call` transform the nodelist returned by querySelectorAll to an array.

Then you simply need to loop on them and add the logic. You also need to stock the last opened container in a variable to be able to close it easily.

```
// First container should be opened by default
let currentContainer = document.querySelector('.container');
currentContainer.classList.add('open');

for (container in containerArray) {
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const clickedContainer = e.target;
    clickedContainer.classList.add('open');
    currentContainer.classList.remove('open');
    currentContainer = clickedContainer;
  });
}
```